# $3$ cards add up to $p$

Tags: probability

I came up with a probability problem:

> A set of $n$ cards each has a different whole number from 1 to $n$. If
>   $3$ different cards are drawn randomly from the deck, what is the probability
>   that the sum of the $3$ cards' values add up to $p$, where $p$ is a
>   positive whole number and $p \leq n$?

What I have so far is the number of combinations:
$$
_nC_3 = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}
$$
I know my answer will be
$$
\frac{(number \; of \; combinations \; that \; add \; up \; to \; p)}{_nC_3}
$$

I'm not even sure if it's possible to solve, so any hints or solutions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order to solve the number of combinations that add up to $p$, you can start by looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)
and then find a way to take out the ones that have repeating numbers

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!!